# Mapped array assignment through ternary operator fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, arrow-functions

I'm new to reactjs and I'm trying to render jsx based on a condition using a ternary operator but it throws an error: `Line 22:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`.
Here is the code:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.length > 0 ?
            this.state.posts.map(elem=>{
                <div class="col s12 m7">
                    <h2 class="header">{elem.title}</h2>
                    <div class="card horizontal">
                        <div class="card-stacked">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>{elem.body}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-action">
                                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })
            :null;
```

I tried including the first return if `this.state.posts.length > 0` is true, in parenthesis `( )` but no good.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the jsx from the function passed to `map` method.

Use `return` inside the function passed to `map` method.

```
const posts =
  this.state.posts.length > 0
    ? this.state.posts.map(elem => {
        return (
          <div className="col s12 m7">
            <h2 className="header">{elem.title}</h2>
            <div className="card horizontal">
              <div className="card-stacked">
                <div className="card-content">
                  <p>{elem.body}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-action">
                  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    : null;
```

You can also use `()` for implicit `return`.

```
const posts =
  this.state.posts.length > 0
    ? this.state.posts.map(elem => (
        <div className="col s12 m7">
          <h2 className="header">{elem.title}</h2>
          <div className="card horizontal">
            <div className="card-stacked">
              <div className="card-content">
                <p>{elem.body}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    : null;
```

Also use `className` for `class` inside jsx.